# how to define local video-js.swf path in angular2 application?

Tags: angular, video.js

We are developing an angular application which uses rtmp/flv streaming on videojs . Project needs video-js.swf and goes to http://vjs.zencdn.net/swf/5.3.0/video-js.swf page to download it. In case of internet outage or delay, we want to define local path of it. That swf is automatically located in node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.swf folder but it doesnot work, it still goes to http://vjs.zencdn.net/swf/5.3.0/video-js.swf page.

We put below code to html page but it does not work. Js scripts are not directly working on angular projects.

```
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

Number of video instances in our project is not static it may change dynamically so we have to define it globally, below code is not also applicable for our project.

```
var player = videojs('vid', {
  flash: {
    swf: '...'
  }
});
```

Is there any angular based solution to this problem?

Comment: Why passing options.flash.swf to videojs on each player initialization is not applicable for your project? You can store default options in global varaible like `var videojsOptions = { flash: { swf: '...' } };` and then use it each time.

Comment: is it working. I am facing same issue.